# Number of true sentences

Tags: logical-deduction

You are given a sheet of paper with $100$ sentences, in the form of: There are exactly $x$ wrong sentences on this sheet.

> There is exactly $1$ wrong sentence on this sheet.
>
> There are exactly $2$ wrong sentences on this sheet.
>
> ...
>
> There are exactly $99$ wrong sentences on this sheet.
>
> There are exactly $100$ wrong sentences on this sheet.

Your task is find out which sentence says the truth (there can be only one).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by the wording of the sentences: Does "There is 1 wrong sentence on this sheet" mean "There is exactly 1 wrong sentence on this sheet," or does it mean "There exists 1 wrong sentence on this sheet (but there may be more)"?

If it is the first case, the answer is **99**, because there are 100 sentences total on the sheet, and all but one of them are wrong.

If it is the second case, the answer is **50**. Sentences #1 to #50 inclusive are correct, and sentences #51 to #100 inclusive are incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for my wording. Your first case is what i meant. I edited the answer to match the wordings.